# p:inputNumber won't accept values less than 1

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml, myfaces

```
<p:inputNumber id="zeroToOne" minValue="0.0" maxValue="1.0"
    value="#{myBean.office.zeroToOne}" />
```

When entering any value less than 1, (for example '0.8') it gives the following message:

'0.8' must be a number consisting of more than one or more digits. '0.8' must be a number between -2147483648 and 2147483647 Example: 21

But if I enter '1.0' it accepts... why is this? How can I make inputNumber accept values less than '1.0'?

(JSF 2.2, MyFaces 2.2, PrimeFaces 6.0)

Comment: Not too familiar with primeFaces, but you could try the `decimalPlaces` attribute.

Comment: What type exactly is `zeroToOne`? Error message suggests that it's actually an `Integer` or `int`, but that's a too obvious mistake.

Comment: @BalusC That's it! Thanks.